# Postgresql Foreign Key Actions - Delete Attribute and Change Other Attributes Related to This

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I create 3 tables just like image. [image: ER_Diagram]Each students can be enrolled multiple class I tried to build one to many relation.

What I want to do is, when a student is deleted from the "Student" table, the course in which the student is registered in the "Bridge" table returns to null. How can I do this operations with postgresql (pgAdmin 4), can you help me please? Thank you...

Comment: Hint:  cascading foreign key contraint.

Comment: I use cascading but this time delete the all rows related this students. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: For a bridge table, the arrows in your diagram are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the `on delete set null` option to foreign keys constraints. The `create table` statement for `bridge` would look like:

```
create table bridge (
    std_id int references students(std_id) on delete set null,
    class_id int references class(class_id)
);
```

I am unsure that `set null` is your best pick for such a bridge table though. This leaves "gaps" in your data that do not make a lot of sense. `on delete cascade` would probably make more sense - and you could apply it to both foreign keys:

```
create table bridge (
    std_id int references students(std_id)  on delete cascade,
    class_id int references class(class_id) on delete cascade
);
```

That way, the bridge table is properly cleaned up when any parent record is dropped. This also opens the way to set up a composite primary key made of both columns in the bridge table.

Comment: Thank you for answer @GMB. However What I want to do is that when I delete the student, the student remains in the bridge table, but the course the student takes is null.

Comment: @Sun: this does not really make sense. Why keep that row in the table when the parent row is gone? Foreign keys cannot do that; actually, they exist to *prevent* that.